# How to expand a range of values stored in two cells (start and end in two colums) to rows (longer version) in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help or suggest, I would like to automate this process in Pandas or any other module in Python such that I can do further processing. I already have a VBA script but it takes forever in Excel, I hope a python script will be quicker.

The current dataframe looks like this
df_original ={
'TOWN_NAME':['ZAKARIYA PARK','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1', 'ZWAVEL' ,'ZWAVEL EXTENSION 1'],
'FH_TYPE': ['GP', 'AH', 'SUB', 'D'],
'SG_NO' : ['A16/1987', 'A2269/1987','A3754/1987','A1108/1988'],
'ERF_FROM': [1,9,430,564],
'ERF_TO': [5,428,562,686]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_original)
df

[current data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jagyp.png)

The desired output is;

df_exp ={
'TOWN_NAME':['ZAKARIYA PARK','ZAKARIYA PARK', 'ZAKARIYA PARK' ,'ZAKARIYA PARK','ZAKARIYA PARK','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1','ZAKARIYA PARK EXTENSION 1'],
'FH_TYPE': ['GP','GP','GP','GP','GP', 'AH','AH','AH','AH','AH','AH','AH','AH','AH'],
'SG_NO' : ['A16/1987','A16/1987','A16/1987','A16/1987','A16/1987', 'A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987','A2269/1987'],
'ERF_FROM': [1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9],
'ERF_TO': [5,5,5,5,5,428,428,428,428,428,428,428,428,428],
'ERF_EXP':[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
}

df_expanded = pd.DataFrame(df_exp)
df_expanded

[desired data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5TPs.png)

Comment: [Please don't post you sample data/desired output data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). We want to help you, but we're not going to retype all that input data. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df
   a  b  from  to
0  c  d     1   5
1  e  f     8  12
```

You can `.reindex()` with `.repeat()` to expand the rows and `.groupby().cumcount()` to add the `exp` column.

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['to'] + 1 - df['from']))
df['exp'] = df['from'] + df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

result:

```
>>> df
   a  b  from  to  exp
0  c  d     1   5    1
1  c  d     1   5    2
2  c  d     1   5    3
3  c  d     1   5    4
4  c  d     1   5    5
5  e  f     8  12    8
6  e  f     8  12    9
7  e  f     8  12   10
8  e  f     8  12   11
9  e  f     8  12   12
```